# Merge together multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I'm working on a script where I want to create one dataframe from a series of files with annual baseball data in them.

I'm relatively new to R and I feel like the way I wrote `get_seasons_range()` is probably more like writing C# in R, rather than doing it the idiomatic R way. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
read_season <- function(yearID) {
  season = read.csv(paste("../retrosheetData/gamelog/GL", yearID, ".TXT", sep=""))
  glheaders = read.csv("../retrosheetData/gamelog/game_log_header.csv")
  names(season) = names(glheaders)
  return(season)
}

read_season_range <- function(year_range) {
  seasons = read_season(year_range[1])

  for(y in year_range) {
    if(y == year_range[1])
      next

    s = read_season(y)
    seasons = rbind(seasons, s)
  }

  return(seasons)
}

sixties = read_season_range(1960:1969)
```

Comment: just small notes - many of your `= `can be replaced by `<-` what is often considered good style, and you might consider reading glheaders outside of the function as it is not supposed to change.  Also you could write the for loop as `for (y in year_range[-1])` so you can skip the nasty if.

Comment: I've seen it written other places that `<-` is preferable to `=` but I haven't seen it explained why. I find it annoying to type the arrow (two characters and the shift key) when my fingers are already trained to hit the equals key from every other programming language. Admittedly, that's not a really good reason...

Comment: of course - it's not an error just a matter of style guideline to follow. eg. [this](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml).  I think it originates from the fact that in some statistical languages `=` is the comparison operator, also `<-` and `=` are evaluated differently when in the argument of a function.  Most editors for R offer some kind of shortcut to type `<-`  maybe you can check the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for` loop can be replaced with a `lapply` statement.
Using base R functions, your `read_season_range` example is equivalent to the following one-liner:

```
sixties <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1960:1969, read_season))
```

or to wrap it in a function:

```
read_season_range <- function(year_range) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(year_range, read_season))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions:

- `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(1960:1969, read_season))`
- `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(1960:1969, read_season))`
- `plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(1960:1969, read_season))`

The fastest is `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package.

Comparison of the performance:

```
LDF <- list(
    data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
    data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
    data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
    data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    do.call(rbind, LDF),
    plyr::rbind.fill(LDF), 
    dplyr::bind_rows(LDF),
    data.table::rbindlist(LDF))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>         do.call(rbind, LDF) 822.387 908.9395 1008.4699 949.0085 987.5020 2800.581   100   b
#>       plyr::rbind.fill(LDF) 751.549 837.6055  960.6077 867.8145 932.1825 2639.683   100   b
#>       dplyr::bind_rows(LDF) 165.354 196.5525  218.4784 214.0425 236.4690  400.057   100  a 
#>  data.table::rbindlist(LDF) 214.878 250.4435  278.0317 270.5885 295.2610  438.430   100  a
```